# Executing a php script located on server via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, python, ajax

I have a website hosted on server, now what I want is to run a .php script (Also located on the same server) when someone presses the submit button in the website.

Following is the ajax code

```
$.ajax({url: "/test.php",
  success: function(response){
      console.log("Success",response);
    }
  });
```

My test.php consists of

```
<?php
//exec('sudo -u www-data python /var/www/html/test.py');
echo "PHP Script Ran";
mkdir("/var/www/html/test", 0700);
?>
```

When I navigate to ip_address/test.php, the `echo` message is displayed correctly but the `mkdir` command doesn't seem to be executed as there is no folder created in my server's directory.

Also I want to know, how can I run this test.php script when someone presses the submit button in my website.

The Javascript code is

```
var $ = jQuery;
var timestamp = Number(new Date());
var form = document.querySelector("form");
var database = firebase.database();
form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  var ary = $(form).serializeArray();
  var obj = {};
  for (var a = 0; a < ary.length; a++) obj[ary[a].name] = ary[a].value;
    console.log("JSON",obj);
  firebase.database().ref('users/' + timestamp).set(obj);
  database.ref('users/' + timestamp).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    console.log("Received value",snapshot.val());
    $.ajax({
      url: "/test.php",
      success: function(response){
        console.log("Success",response);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: `event.preventDefault();` is missing to stop the form submission.

Comment: @Jai so I added this after `form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {event.preventDefault(); .....` but how do I execute the php script now?
After getting it from ajax

Comment: It seems like a permission problem: probably the script `test.php` hasn't the permission to add that folder. There is also the possibility that the path `/var/www/html` doesn't exist on the remote server. These are my ideas...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case it's recommended to use `mkdir` within `try...catch` function and capture the error if it's the case.

On the other hand [`mkidr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) will return a boolean value: `true` if the directory creation was successful or `false` in the case of a failure.

**1.version**

```
try {
    mkdir("/var/www/html/test", 0700, true);
} catch ($ex Exception) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

**2.version**

```
if (!mkdir("/var/www/html/test", 0700, true)) {
    echo 'Failed to create folder...';
}
```

If `mkdir` cannot create the folder two things you need to check: if the folder exist and if it has the right permissions. By this i mean if the user group is set to apache (because apache, through web browser is executing the mkdir command) and second if apache (`www-data`) has the necessary permissions to execute this command.

Comment: Ok, so I did this and the response that I get is "Failed to create folder.." so probably some permission issues, I'll have a look at that
Just one more thing, the command `alert(response);` executes the script on my server?
I am a bit new to this so this part wan't clear to me.

Comment: it't a javascript action, it has nothing to do with server side. please check my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks, it works :)
Had to use this guide to set the correct permissions [http://fideloper.com/user-group-permissions-chmod-apache](http://fideloper.com/user-group-permissions-chmod-apache)

Answer (score 1):

Revise your **php.ini** in the server, the tag **disable_functions** = "..." and making sure that mkdir not this included in the list.